# Magento custom variables / static blocks assigned to a specific backend user?

Tags: magento, permissions

Is there any way to make some of the custom variables or static blocks belong to a specific backend user so only the privileged user can edit their values?

Usually a site would have lots of global static blocks that are displayed across the site. They are mission critical and can only be managed by the technical team.

However there are other static blocks or custom variables such as a promotional offers, or a dynamic delivery turnaround by changing work load, etc. that should be managed by catalog editors, production or marketing departments, etc.

I tried System > Permissions > Roles but the Static Block option seems to be granting full privileges of ALL static blocks as a whole.

So is there any way to discriminate static blocks editing privileges per backend user?

Or is there any other simple way to achieve this? Backend values or HTML blocks that are only editable to certain users and that can be displayed frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new filed for Static Blocks and Admin Users say `custom_admin_role` and filter the static blocks when a user goes to static blocks section using this field. Then only the `custom_admin_role` value matched static blocks will be displayed to the user. This need lot of core hacks or you need to rewrite the blocks.